# Implementing CRYSTALS-Kyber using BouncyCastle Java

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, post-quantum-cryptography

Could anyone help lead me in the right direction to even just generate a keypair using Kyber? I've tried to search for BouncyCastle examples but I am unable to find any to go off.

I'm trying to benchmark some current algorithms such as AES/RSA, which I have working perfectly, but I am unable to make any progress on even getting started on Kyber. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried to search it on Google for examples, the developers have implementations C# and even Java without BouncyCastle on their website. They mention it is available on BouncyCastle but I cannot find any documentation for it even to help implement it.

Comment: What is Kyber? This question could use a few more details.

Comment: @President James K. Polk: CHRYSTALS-KYBER is a Key Exchange Mechanism algorithm that was chosen by NIST in 2022 as a "Selected Algorithms: Public-key Encryption and Key-establishment Algorithms" (see: https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/post-quantum-cryptography/selected-algorithms-2022). It should be safe against **Post Quantum attacks**.

Comment: @MichaelFehr Noting that it uses key encapsulation rather than key agreement / DH like. Of course, with a relatively OK key pair generation time that should not matter much, but it is a different scheme. I'd personally call it "key establishment" rather than "key exchange" as the secret is only communicated in one direction but yeah, language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can provide a complete example for CHRYSTALS-KYBER using Bouncy Castle. It generates a keypair, calculates an encryption key and decryption key.

There are three parameter specs available:

```
KyberParameterSpec.kyber512
KyberParameterSpec.kyber768
KyberParameterSpec.kyber1024
```

As the class was used in a larger Android project it may not work properly stand alone.

I tested the algorithm using Bouncy Castle version 1.72.

This is the full code:

```
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.SecretKeyWithEncapsulation;
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.spec.KEMExtractSpec;
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.spec.KEMGenerateSpec;
import org.bouncycastle.pqc.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastlePQCProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.pqc.jcajce.spec.KyberParameterSpec;
import org.bouncycastle.util.Arrays;

import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;

import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;

public class PqcChrystalsKyberKem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        // we do need the regular Bouncy Castle file that includes the PQC provider
        // get Bouncy Castle here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk18on
        // tested with BC version 1.72
        if (Security.getProvider("BCPQC") == null) {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastlePQCProvider());
        }
        String print = run(false);
        System.out.println(print);
    }

    public static String run(boolean truncateKeyOutput) {
        String out = "PQC Chrystals-Kyber KEM";
        out += "\n" + "\n************************************\n" +
                "* # # SERIOUS SECURITY WARNING # # *\n" +
                "* This program is a CONCEPT STUDY  *\n" +
                "* for the algorithm                *\n" +
                "* Chrystals-Kyber [key exchange    *\n" +
                "* mechanism]                       *\n" +
                "* The program is using an          *\n" +
                "* parameter set that I cannot      *\n" +
                "* check for the correctness of the *\n" +
                "* output and other details         *\n" +
                "*                                  *\n" +
                "*    DO NOT USE THE PROGRAM IN     *\n" +
                "*    ANY PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT    *\n" +
                "************************************";

        // as there are 3 parameter sets available the program runs all of them
        KyberParameterSpec[] kyberParameterSpecs = {
                KyberParameterSpec.kyber512,
                KyberParameterSpec.kyber768,
                KyberParameterSpec.kyber1024
        };

        // statistics
        int nrOfSpecs = kyberParameterSpecs.length;
        String[] parameterSpecName = new String[nrOfSpecs];
        int[] privateKeyLength = new int[nrOfSpecs];
        int[] publicKeyLength = new int[nrOfSpecs];
        int[] encryptionKeyLength = new int[nrOfSpecs];
        int[] encapsulatedKeyLength = new int[nrOfSpecs];
        boolean[] encryptionKeysEquals = new boolean[nrOfSpecs];

        out += "\n\n****************************************\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < nrOfSpecs; i++) {
            // generation of the Chrystals-Kyber key pair
            KyberParameterSpec kyberParameterSpec = kyberParameterSpecs[i];
            String kyberParameterSpecName = kyberParameterSpec.getName();
            parameterSpecName[i] = kyberParameterSpecName;
            out += "\n" + "Chrystals-Kyber KEM with parameterset " + kyberParameterSpecName;
            KeyPair keyPair = generateChrystalsKyberKeyPair(kyberParameterSpec);

            // get private and public key
            PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
            PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

            // storing the key as byte array
            byte[] privateKeyByte = privateKey.getEncoded();
            byte[] publicKeyByte = publicKey.getEncoded();
            out += "\n" + "\ngenerated private key length: " + privateKeyByte.length;
            out += "\n" + "generated public key length:  " + publicKeyByte.length;
            privateKeyLength[i] = privateKeyByte.length;
            publicKeyLength[i] = publicKeyByte.length;

            // generate the keys from a byte array
            PrivateKey privateKeyLoad = getChrystalsKyberPrivateKeyFromEncoded(privateKeyByte);
            PublicKey publicKeyLoad = getChrystalsKyberPublicKeyFromEncoded(publicKeyByte);

            // generate the encryption key and the encapsulated key
            out += "\n" + "\nEncryption side: generate the encryption key and the encapsulated key";
            SecretKeyWithEncapsulation secretKeyWithEncapsulationSender = pqcGenerateChrystalsKyberEncryptionKey(publicKeyLoad);
            byte[] encryptionKey = secretKeyWithEncapsulationSender.getEncoded();
            out += "\n" + "encryption key length: " + encryptionKey.length
                    + " key: " + bytesToHex(secretKeyWithEncapsulationSender.getEncoded());
            byte[] encapsulatedKey = secretKeyWithEncapsulationSender.getEncapsulation();
            out += "\n" + "encapsulated key length: " + encapsulatedKey.length + " key: " + (truncateKeyOutput ?shortenString(bytesToHex(encapsulatedKey)):bytesToHex(encapsulatedKey));

            encryptionKeyLength[i] = encryptionKey.length;
            encapsulatedKeyLength[i] = encapsulatedKey.length;

            out += "\n" + "\nDecryption side: receive the encapsulated key and generate the decryption key";
            byte[] decryptionKey = pqcGenerateChrystalsKyberDecryptionKey(privateKeyLoad, encapsulatedKey);
            out += "\n" + "decryption key length: " + decryptionKey.length + " key: " + bytesToHex(decryptionKey);
            boolean keysAreEqual = Arrays.areEqual(encryptionKey, decryptionKey);
            out += "\n" + "decryption key is equal to encryption key: " + keysAreEqual;
            encryptionKeysEquals[i] = keysAreEqual;
            out += "\n\n****************************************\n";
        }

        out += "\n" + "Test results";
        out += "\n" + "parameter spec name  priKL   pubKL encKL capKL  keyE"   + "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < nrOfSpecs; i++) {
            String out1 = String.format("%-20s%6d%8d%6d%6d%6b%n", parameterSpecName[i], privateKeyLength[i], publicKeyLength[i], encryptionKeyLength[i], encapsulatedKeyLength[i], encryptionKeysEquals[i]);
            out += out1;
        }
        out += "\n" + "Legend: priKL privateKey length, pubKL publicKey length, encKL encryption key length, "
                + "capKL encapsulated key length" + "\n";
        out += "****************************************\n";
        return out;
    }

    private static String shortenString (String input) {
        if (input != null && input.length() > 32) {
            return input.substring(0, 32) + " ...";
        } else {
            return input;
        }
    }

    private static KeyPair generateChrystalsKyberKeyPair(KyberParameterSpec kyberParameterSpec) {
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("KYBER", "BCPQC");
            kpg.initialize(kyberParameterSpec, new SecureRandom());
            KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
            return kp;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static SecretKeyWithEncapsulation pqcGenerateChrystalsKyberEncryptionKey(PublicKey publicKey) {
        KeyGenerator keyGen = null;
        try {
            keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("KYBER", "BCPQC");
            keyGen.init(new KEMGenerateSpec((PublicKey) publicKey, "AES"), new SecureRandom());
            SecretKeyWithEncapsulation secEnc1 = (SecretKeyWithEncapsulation) keyGen.generateKey();
            return secEnc1;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static byte[] pqcGenerateChrystalsKyberDecryptionKey(PrivateKey privateKey, byte[] encapsulatedKey) {
        KeyGenerator keyGen = null;
        try {
            keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("KYBER", "BCPQC");
            keyGen.init(new KEMExtractSpec((PrivateKey) privateKey, encapsulatedKey, "AES"), new SecureRandom());
            SecretKeyWithEncapsulation secEnc2 = (SecretKeyWithEncapsulation) keyGen.generateKey();
            return secEnc2.getEncoded();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static PrivateKey getChrystalsKyberPrivateKeyFromEncoded(byte[] encodedKey) {
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8EncodedKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = null;
        try {
            keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("KYBER", "BCPQC");
            return keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8EncodedKeySpec);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static PublicKey getChrystalsKyberPublicKeyFromEncoded(byte[] encodedKey) {
        X509EncodedKeySpec x509EncodedKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey);
        try {
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("KYBER", "BCPQC");
            return keyFactory.generatePublic(x509EncodedKeySpec);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b : bytes) result.append(Integer.toString((b & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Michael Fehr: Thank you for the code example, it runs perfectly. I want to learn and understand how to create this as I hope to run some benchmarks for a project I am about to start.

Can I ask, where did you learn about how to impelment this? I do want to do another 4-5 post-quantum algorithms but I cannot find much code regarding bouncycastle on how to actually implement them. 

My course only did some Cryptography with AES bouncycastle last year but thats all we get to do which is unfortunate as I have a interest in the subject, especially quantum algorithms and how they work.

Comment: I got the information from BC's tests (see provider tests: https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/tree/master/prov/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/pqc/jcajce/provider/test and core tests: https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/tree/master/core/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/pqc/crypto/test).

Answer (score 1):

This is a hybrid encryption mechanism using Kyber and AES. Here I am using Bouncycastle 1.77 with Java 11 for the implementation

Client creates the keypair using Kyber, and send the public key to the Server

```
private static KeyPair generateKeyPair() Exception {
    //generate key pair
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("Kyber", "BCPQC");
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(KyberParameterSpec.kyber512, new SecureRandom());
    return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
}
```

Server use the public key to generate a shared secret, encapsulate it, and send the encapsulation to the Client.

```
private static SecretKeyWithEncapsulation generateSecretKeySender(PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {
    // You will request a key generator
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Kyber", "BCPQC");
    // You will set up a KEM Generate Spec with the public key
    KEMGenerateSpec kemGenerateSpec = new KEMGenerateSpec(publicKey, "Secret");
    // Now you can initialize the key generator with the kem generate spec and generate out share secret
    keyGenerator.init(kemGenerateSpec);
    return  (SecretKeyWithEncapsulation)keyGenerator.generateKey();
}
```

Client decapsulates the shared secret using private key.

```
private static SecretKeyWithEncapsulation generateSecretKeyReciever(PrivateKey privateKey, byte[] encapsulation) throws Exception {
    // You will set up a KEM Extract Spec with the receiver private key - in this case you need the encapsulation
    // generated by the receiver as well.
    KEMExtractSpec kemExtractSpec = new KEMExtractSpec(privateKey, encapsulation, "Secret");
    // You will request a key generator
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KEM_ALGORITHM, PROVIDER);
    // Now you can initialize the key generator with the kem extract spec and retrieve the KEM secret.
    keyGenerator.init(kemExtractSpec);
    return (SecretKeyWithEncapsulation)keyGenerator.generateKey();
}
```

Since now both Client and server has the shared secret, they can use AES to encrypt and share data between them.

```
public static String encrypt(String plainText, byte[] key) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedBytes);
}

public static String decrypt(String encryptedText, byte[] key) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedText);
    byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(decodedBytes);
    return new String(decryptedBytes);
}
```

Main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastlePQCProvider());

    KeyPair keyPair = generateKeyPair();
    SecretKeyWithEncapsulation initKeyWithEnc = generateSecretKeySender(keyPair.getPublic());
    byte[] encapsulation = initKeyWithEnc.getEncapsulation();
    String originalText = "This is a secret message.";
    String encryptedText = encrypt(originalText, initKeyWithEnc.getEncoded());
    SecretKeyWithEncapsulation recKeyWithEnc = generateSecretKeyReciever(keyPair.getPrivate(), encapsulation);
    String decryptedText = decrypt(encryptedText, recKeyWithEnc.getEncoded());
}
```

The final code can be found [here](https://medium.com/@hwupathum/using-crystals-kyber-kem-for-hybrid-encryption-with-java-0ab6c70d41fc)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your complete code.